Special Characters Error While converting STRING to JSON in python
I have following string coming from 3rd party api.
teststring = '{"@speccialcharacterssample": "/special.character.test.Sample","content": {"description": "Some number **451000**, Some Time **Monday, April 8th, UTC 11:00**. \n# BackSpace\nBreakline\nMore Special Character[Full Change Log](https://example.com/v1.0.1).\n# Special Character Test\ncomma test, colon test: breakline\nBreakline followed by hashes test\n## Breakline\nnew test **451000**, time **Monday, April 8th, UTC 11:00**. Square Brackets [HERE](https://example.com/451000).\nThats all.","plan": {"info": "{\"bin\":{\"example/zya32\":\"https://example.com/v1.0.1/version-v1.0.1-example-xya32?check=asda43tsd23423scasq\"}}"}}}'

When i try to convert it to json using code
teststring_json = json.loads(teststring)

It throws following error
  teststring_json = json.loads(teststring)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 1408 (char 1407)

I tried several ways to remove special characters but it never works. e.g
updated_json = teststring.replace('\\"', '\\\\"')

You need to go back to your 3rd party to get them to produce valid json. You seem to have embedded control characters which are not allowed and should have been escaped.

there are a lot of mistakes in this JSON.

Despite the correct comments from @Mohammedalmalki and @quamrana, I did get it to work. By taking your text and saving it to a file I got json.load(fp) to correctly parse it.

@OldBoy which python version you used? I am using 3.11 or 3.10

I tested it using Python 3.10. But I really could not figure out why it worked reading a file but not as a direct string.
